# python deep copy of ROS message

Tags: ros, python, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish two odometry messages that share most of the fields.
To avoid copying all the elements one by one I try:

> > odom_new = Odometry(odom_old)

But this give me an error.

> > File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/message.py", line 362, in **init**
> > raise TypeError("Invalid number of arguments, args should be %s"%str(self.**slots**)+" args are"+str(args))
> > TypeError: Invalid number of arguments, args should be ['header', 'child_frame_id', 'pose', 'twist']

Then I try:

> > odom_new = Odometry(odom_old.header, odom_old.child_frame_id, odom_old.pose, odom_old.twist)

This doesn't give me any errors but just creates a pointer from the new object to the old one. Then, when the new one is modified the old one too (I need an independent object)

After this I try:

> > import copy

> > odom_new = copy.deepcopy(odom_old)

But again this solution fails.

> > odom_new = copy.deepcopy(odom_old)
> > AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

Any Idea about how to create a deep copy of a ROS message in Python?
Sorry, my Python knowledge is very limited :P!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37682/python-deep-copy-of-ros-message/) by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-02**:
What's the failure you are getting? Please always post backtraces and error messages when posting questions to save your and other people's time.

**Comment by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on 2012-07-02**:
Added error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`copy.deepcopy` is the recommended way of creating a deep copy of a message, according to [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2430).

**Edit**:
You probably named a function copy after the import line. Python has only one namespace for variables and functions (in contrast to Common Lisp for instance), i.e. by naming a function `copy`, you overwrite the package `copy`. Either do

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

and just call `deepcopy`, not `copy.deepcopy` or rename your function. You can also import the module `copy` under a different name:

```
import copy as copy_module
```

Then you can call the deepcopy function like this:

```
odom_new = copy_module.deepcopy(odom_old)
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3